Animation of VStack child inside NavigationStack animates other properties
Why is this happening?
Here is a POC:
struct POCNavigationStackBehavior: View {
    @State private var animating = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                    .fill(.quaternary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .opacity(animating ? 0.3 : 1)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.75).repeatForever(), value: animating)
                    .onAppear {
                        animating.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


I just want to animate the rect's opacity but its position is also being animated from (0, 0) to where it's supposed to be.

...to animate the rect's opacity you could try a different approach using withAnimation that changes a var opacity
as shown in the code example:
struct POCNavigationStackBehavior: View {
    @State private var opacity = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                    .fill(.quaternary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.75).repeatForever()) {
                            opacity = 0.3
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        POCNavigationStackBehavior()
    }
}

